# How to Pass dictionary as the value of another dictionary?

Tags: c#

```
var for_cat_dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var category_Dict = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();

for_cat_dict.Add(bean.getId(), bean.getId());
```

Now I want to add elements to the category_dict. So I tried..

```
category_Dict.Add(bean.getId(),[for_cat_dict]);
```

But it doesnt work... any solutions??

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? What errors are you getting? Why are you using `[]` when adding?

Comment: They are some poorly names variables.

Comment: Are you sure you want the value of every item in the category_Dict Dictionary to be another Dictionary?

Comment: Yes that is the requirement, bean is another dictionary that already has some key and values, if i remove [],it shows up an error, if [] is thr it says ") expected"..

Comment: Worked :) i removed [], now its working fine .. dunno what was wrong :( thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but

```
Category_Dict.Add(bean.getId(), for_cat_dict);
```

should at least *compile*. Whether it'll do what you want is another matter - it's not clear whether these are local variables, fields etc. (It also looks like you're not following .NET naming conventions in various ways...)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> for_cat_dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Category_Dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

Category_Dict.Add("somekey", for_cat_dict);
```